# How to select only one Radiobutton in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have two radiobutton in my `GUI` but i want to able select only one at a time with the code below am able to select both `radiobutton` . I tried the `checkbutton` which also i can select both options.

```
from tkinter import *


def content():
    if not option1.get() and not option2.get():
        print("not allowed, select one dude")
    else:
        print("welcome dude")

    option1.set(False) 
    option2.set(False)   


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

option1 = BooleanVar(value=False)
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="MALE", value=1, var=option1)
R1.pack()

option2 = BooleanVar(value=False)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="FEMALE", value=2, var=option2)
R2.pack()

b = Button(root, text="print", command=content)
b.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must bind both radiobuttons to the same variable.
Besides, the variable will receive the value specified in the `value` keyword argument.
I suggest you do the following:

```
option = StringVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="MALE", value="male", var=option)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="FEMALE", value="female", var=option)
```

You can know what item is currently selected, by tracing the `option` variable, and by calling its `get` method.
For instance, the following will print either `"male"` or `"female"` whenever the corresponding radiobutton is checked.

```
def print_var(*_):
    print(option.get())

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

option = StringVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="MALE", value="male", var=option)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="FEMALE", value="female", var=option)
R1.pack()
R2.pack()

option.trace('w', print_var)

root.mainloop()
```

A more complete example, according to your demand.
This script will display a window with two radiobuttons and a button.
When the button is clicked, a message is printed that depends upon whether an option was selected or not.

```
from tkinter import *

def validate():
    value = option.get()
    if value == "male":
        print("Welcome dude")
    elif value == "female":
        print("Welcome gurl")
    else:
        print("An option must be selected")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

option = StringVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="MALE", value="male", var=option)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="FEMALE", value="female", var=option)
button = Button(root, text="OK", command=validate)

R1.pack()
R2.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

As a side note, you should never import a module with a star, eg `from tkinter import *`.
In short, it pollutes the namespace. More on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/7051394).

Comment: I dont want print the value of the radiobutton selected but i want one to be selected if not should print ** not allowed**

Comment: if one is selected should print welcome dude but the challenge now is am able to select both radiobuttons but i want only one to be selected.

Comment: @NewpyBoi That's a proof of concept, you can do whatever you want from this point. Simply check in your button callback that the `option` variable's value is set.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it that i found is this -
you have to give them both the same variable so that compiler can know that the user can only choose one...

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("100x100")
var = IntVar()

radio = Radiobutton(window, text="this", variable=var, value=1)
radio.pack()
radio2 = Radiobutton(window, text="or this", variable=var, value=2)
radio2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are wanting to create one radio button with multiple values which only allows one selection? You would be better to populate an array and run a loop to fill the radio button. Perhaps something like this?

```
from tkinter import *




root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

GENDERS = [
    ("Male", "M"),
    ("Female", "F"),
    ("Other", "O")
]

v = StringVar()
v.set("L")  # initialize

for text, gender in GENDERS:
    b = Radiobutton(root, text=text,
                    variable=v, value=gender)
    b.pack(anchor=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: whether or not they use an array is irrelevant. It's good programming practice, but what they want can be done without an array so your answer is a little bit misleading.